# how to pass a variable back to root navigation controller from the UIViewController using Protocol and Delegate in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

[Xcode Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNhlI.png)

As you can see in the image attached I have the root navigation controller called - Notifications and a UIViewController called NotificationsController.

So my Question is how can i pass a variable from NotificationsController back to Notifications using Protocol and Delegate, because in this case there is no segue but a default relationship between them.

Is my question correct or is there another way to do what i need.

Any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To reference the navigation controller from the view controller (it is an optional so you need to handle that):

```
// self is a UIViewController
self.navigationController
```

To reference the view controller from the navigation controller:

```
// self is a UINavigationController
let index = // Index of the view controller. You may need to iterate over viewControllers to find this.
self.viewControllers[index]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to set up a delegate. As keithbhunter pointed out in his answer, a view controller has a navigationController property that will point to the navigation controller that manages it.

I suggest you define a protocol for the messages you want to send to your navigation controller, and then have your custom subclass of UINavigationController conform to that protocol.

Within the view controllers that are on the navigation controller's stack you can fetch a pointer to your navigation controller and cast it to type `UINavigationController<myNavControllerProtocol>`.

(UINavigationController that conforms to myNavControllerProtocol. I'm working in Objective-C these days and don't remember the exact syntax for that.)